# NUMBERS Is it possible to select all the cells that share the same background colour on an existing table?

Tags: macos, numbers

I have a large(ish) table, which is 75 rows, and 120 columns. so, 9000 cells. They are all empty of data, but some of them have their background fill set to Colour A, and some have it set to Colour B.

I would like to be able to select all the cells that are currently showing as Colour A cells, and change their background fill in one go, rather than have to sit for hours on end, manually selecting the cells individually.

Is this possible, or do I have a long night ahead?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to Select All the cells in the sheet, then in the Format Sidebar,  click the Cell tab. Then in the Fill section of the sidebar, click the color well, then select a fill option. It will say Multiple Fills. You should be able to select No Fill and delete all background (fill) colors:

[image]

Comment: I’m sorry to have wasted your time: it seems someone else has edited my question post, and unwittingly totally changed the question I was asking to something else! I want to be able to select all the cells that are currently one background colour. For example: if I have a mixture of red cells and blue cells, I want to be able to select all the red cells, and NOT the blue cells.

Comment: I have now edited the original to do that it asks the question I need to know the answer to.

Comment: Not a waste of time at all. Happy to help, although in the end it was futile. :-)

Comment: Do you happen to know if there’s a way to do it?